# Is there an independent alert function without any html template in vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

I know other js framework developed the independent message functions like the alert, confirm and prompt function within the primitive javascript that can be invoked anywhere. such as the Ext.Msg() function in Ext.js, the Message() function of the iView.

I implemented the interceptors in my project with axios. I want to show a transit Message alert when any errors occurred. associated with httpstatus code and message from back end occurred.

```js
// Add a response interceptor
_axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  },
  function (error) {
    switch (error.response.status) {
      case 400: error.message = 'Bad request'; break
      case 401: error.message = 'blabla...(401)'; break
      case 403: error.message = 'blabla...(403)'; break
      case 404: error.message = 'blabla...(404)'; break
      case 408: error.message = 'blabla...(408)'; break
      // ...  ...
      case 505: error.message = 'HTTP版本不受支持(505)'; break
      default: error.message = `连接出错(${error.response.status})!`
    }
    alert(error.message);   // I Just want to replace the function with a more pretty message box function
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: I think it's not part of framework and it will not be 
 https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuex/issues/16

Comment: thank your. I think i need the function you mentioned. but if it devloped the new feature, it still a problem to invoke the Vue.$vuetify.confirm within the axios plugin.